# Attribute error from factoryboy for self-referencing SQLAlchemy model

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, factory-boy

I realise a similar question has been posed before (https://github.com/FactoryBoy/factory_boy/issues/173) but I have tried all the suggestions in that ticket and am still having issues creating a self-referencing field in a SQLAlchemy model.

Specifically, when I try creating a ScaleFactory object in a test using this format (as suggested in the ticket):

`new_scale = factories.ScaleFactory(code=test_code, description_student=test_description_student, parent_scale__parent_scale=None)`

I get the following error:

```
  obj = None, name = 'id', default = <class 'factory.declarations._UNSPECIFIED'> . 

  def deepgetattr(obj, name, default=_UNSPECIFIED):
      """Try to retrieve the given attribute of an object, digging on '.'.

      This is an extended getattr, digging deeper if '.' is found.

      Args:
          obj (object): the object of which an attribute should be read
          name (str): the name of an attribute to look up.
          default (object): the default value to use if the attribute wasn't found

      Returns:
          the attribute pointed to by 'name', splitting on '.'.

      Raises:
          AttributeError: if obj has no 'name' attribute.
      """
      try:
          if '.' in name:
              attr, subname = name.split('.', 1)
              return deepgetattr(getattr(obj, attr), subname, default)
          else:
              return getattr(obj, name)
  E           AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'id'
```

My factory model is this:

```
class ScaleFactory(factory.alchemy.SQLAlchemyModelFactory):
    class Meta:
        model = models.Scale
        sqlalchemy_session = models.orm.session

    id = lazy_attribute(lambda o: fake.uuid4())
    ...
    parent_scale_id = factory.SelfAttribute("parent_scale.id")
    parent_scale = factory.SubFactory('application.factories.ScaleFactory')
```

My model is this:

```
class Scale(orm.Model):
    __tablename__ = "scale"
    id = orm.Column(UUID(as_uuid=True), primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4)
    ...
    parent_scale_id = orm.Column(UUID(as_uuid=True), orm.ForeignKey("scale.id"))
    parent_scale = orm.relationship("Scale", remote_side=[id])
```

I've also tried all the other suggestions on that support ticket (@factory.post_generation etc) but all result in an infinite recursion. The only call that does not produce an infinite recursion is that one I've given here, but that results in the AttributeError you see. It's very possible I'm just not understanding what I'm supposed to pass here instead of None as parent_scale__parent_scale. I've tried creating a MagicMock obj as well and passing that as parent_scale but that produced an AttributeError trying to find `__name__`. So I'm totally stuck! Any help is hugely appreciated.

I'm on factory-boy==2.12.0

Answer (score 2):

To answer my own question, in case it helps anyone - a way to do this, to prevent both infinite recursion and the AttributeError, is to pass in a None value as suggested in the original answer (https://github.com/FactoryBoy/factory_boy/issues/173) but also implement a `post_generation` hook to set the `parent_scale_id`:

```
class ScaleFactory(factory.alchemy.SQLAlchemyModelFactory):
    class Meta:
        model = models.Scale
        sqlalchemy_session = models.orm.session

    id = lazy_attribute(lambda o: fake.uuid4())
    ...
    parent_scale = factory.SubFactory("application.factories.ScaleFactory")

    @factory.post_generation
    def parent_scale_id(self, create, _, **__):
        self.parent_scale_id = self.parent_scale.id if self.parent_scale else None
```

Call it like so:

```
new_scale = factories.ScaleFactory(code=test_code, description_student=test_description_student, parent_scale__parent_scale__parent_scale__parent_scale=None)
```

This will give you a Scale with 3 parent Scales.